# Why Headset With Volume Control Functions Different Now And What To Do With Track Skipping Bug?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, music-player, stock-android, bugs, winamp

I am using ZAGGsmartbuds to listen to music and speak with people as it has track switch control and microphone. Pressing track control once activates stock music player to play music and also pauses already playing track, pressing twice skips to next track. When Winamp is launched, it supersedes control from stock music player so I can use Winamp, given application is not killed in RAM. Recently controls changed somehow and now when I try to skip track, it sometimes starts to call last answered number or does not skip to next track. It also starts stock music player even if Winamp is still running. Yesterday I had a bug when tracks randomly started skipping very fast and in the end, audio was gone completely in stock player and when I switched to Winamp, same happened shortly and I had to restart device to regain audio back.

I also had missing audio earlier prior to this until I restarted device but never had tracks skipping.

**HTC Desire S**
**Android 2.3.5 stock**

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling winamp first, and see if the issue is still there. There seems to be, by the sound of it (no pun intended), conflicts with the stock player and winamp, and both are trying to get a stranglehold on the media playing, competing with each other.